# How to cover Catch statement in test class

Tags: apex

I want to cover catch statement in test class i want code that will help us to cover all catch statement in test class in salesforce.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: All depends on what in in the code before the catch statement.

Comment: you need to share your code and the test class you've developed so far. Main code, which you need to cover, is certainly going to help us help you. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd take @Novarg's answer and extend it somewhat:

```
//some other code
yourClass.someMethod('Hello');
try {
    yourClass.someMethod(null);
} catch (NullPointerException e) {
    System.debug ('all ok');
    return;
}
System.assert(false, 'a NullPointerException was expected but was not thrown');
//some other code
```

This waý your test won't fail, the NullPointerException is rather the expected outcome.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your tests to cover some piece of code you have to make sure that the execution will run into this line. So in case you want to test `try-catch` block, you must make sure that `try` part will throw some exception. In this example:

```
public void someMethod(String a) {
    try {
        if (a.size() == 5) {
            // do something
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.debug('something went wrong, exception: ' + e);
    }
}
```

the `try` part will throw an exception if `a` will be null, because you will be trying to dereference a null object(with other words: you will try to call `size()` method on a null object), so execution will jump into the `catch` part. To test this case you should do something like this in your test class:

```
//some other code
yourClass.someMethod('Hello');
yourClass.someMethod(null);
//some other code
```

This will test both `try` and `catch` blocks. And it will even test the code inside your `if`-statement(because the size of 'Hello' is equal to 5)

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late, but still if it helps. This works for me -

**//Main Class**

```
public class AccountHandler{
    public static void insertAccount(Account acc){
        try{
            insert acc;
        }catch(DMLException dex){
            system.debug('dml exception occured: ' + dex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**//Test Class**

```
@IsTest
public class AccountHandlerTest{
    public static testMethod void insertAccountTest(){
        **//Cover try block**
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account');
        AccountHandler.insertAccount(acc);
        
        //Cover catch block
        Account accnt = new Account(); **//drop required field to throw exception deliberately**
        
        **//catch exception you are getting in test class as shown below**
        try{
            AccountHandler.insertAccount(accnt);
        }catch(DMLException dex){
            System.debug ('all right' + dex.getMessage());
            return;
        }
        **System.assert(false, 'a dml exception was expected but was not thrown');**
    }
}
```